# Overload resolution, name lookup and function pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, overload-resolution, argument-dependent-lookup

I have a case where lookup and overload resolution behaves differently:

- for user-defined class *vs* built-in types *vs* std::string
- for direct call *vs* function pointer call

I cannot figure what exact parts of the standard justify these differences.

**Consider the following C++11 code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Test1 {};
struct Test2 {};

template<typename T>
int f(T t) { return 0; }

int f(Test1 t) { return 10; }
int f(int y) { return 20; }

template<typename T>
int use1() { return f(T()); }

template<typename T>
int use2() { auto fp = static_cast<int(*)(T)>(&f); return (*fp)(T()); }

int f(Test2 t) { return 30; }
int f(string s) { return 40; }
int f(double y) { return 50; }

int main() {
    cout << "use1<float>:  " << use1<float>()  << endl;
    cout << "use1<Test1>:  " << use1<Test1>()  << endl;
    cout << "use1<int>:    " << use1<int>()    << endl;
    cout << "use1<Test2>:  " << use1<Test2>()  << endl;
    cout << "use1<string>: " << use1<string>() << endl;
    cout << "use1<double>: " << use1<double>() << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "use2<float>:  " << use2<float>()  << endl;
    cout << "use2<Test1>:  " << use2<Test1>()  << endl;
    cout << "use2<int>:    " << use2<int>()    << endl;
    cout << "use2<Test2>:  " << use2<Test2>()  << endl;
    cout << "use2<string>: " << use2<string>() << endl;
    cout << "use2<double>: " << use2<double>() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output is (same with g++ 6.3 and clang++5.0.0 trunk):**

```
use1<float>:  0
use1<Test1>:  10
use1<int>:    20
use1<Test2>:  30
use1<string>: 0
use1<double>: 0

use2<float>:  0
use2<Test1>:  10
use2<int>:    20
use2<Test2>:  0
use2<string>: 0
use2<double>: 0
```

**Questions:**

1. Why `use1<string>` is different from `use1<Test2>` ? Both types are declared "at the top", both f() overloads are declared at the bottom.
2. Why `use1<Test2>` is different from  `use1<double>`? Corresponding f() overloads are on adjacent lines, is there anything special in treatment of built-in types?
3. Why `use1<Test2>` is different from `use2<Test2>`? The type of a pointer to function in use2 seems to match the calling context in use1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two-phase name lookup. At the point where `use1` is defined, three overloads of `f` are visible via normal lookup. At the point of instantiation, additional overloads may be found - but only by argument-dependent lookup. `Test2` is in global namespace, so `f(Test2)` is found by ADL; whereas `string` is in namespace `std`, and so `f(string)` (which is, obviously, not in namespace `std`) is not found by ADL. `double` has no associated namespaces, and so ADL doesn't kick in at all.

In `use2`, `f` is not a dependent name, and so the second-phase lookup is not performed at all - only overloads visible at the point of definition are considered.

Comment: Thank you! Regarding use2: is there a way in use2<T> to obtain a function pointer that contains address of the exact same overload of f() that is resolved in use1<T>?

Comment: I can't think of any way to "dependify" a name. The standard only envisions the second lookup phase when the name is used in a straight function call, `name(some_args)`, and not other cases where overload resolution may need to be performed.